# How to detect references to out-of-scope stack variables in C++?

Tags: c++, valgrind, stack-memory

Valgrind is useful for detecting lingering references to free'd objects on the heap.  However, it doesn't seem to have this feature for lingering references to out-of-scope variables on the stack.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct CharHolder {
    const char ch;
    CharHolder(char _ch) : ch(_ch) {}
};

struct Printer {
    const CharHolder& ref;
    Printer(const CharHolder& _ref) : ref(_ref) {}
    void print() {
        std::cout << &ref << ": " << ref.ch << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    // g++ -O0: prints 'x'
    // g++ -O3: prints undefined character
    Printer p1(CharHolder('x'));
    p1.print();

    // g++: prints undefined character
    CharHolder* h = new CharHolder('x');
    Printer p2(*h);
    delete h;
    p2.print();
}
```

The first example, with `p1`, is one where the printer holds a reference to an out-of-scope stack variable, since `CharHolder('x')` is destructed as soon as the construction of `p1` is complete.

The second example, with `p2`, is one where the printer holds a reference to a heap variable, which is free'd before `p2` attempts to reference it in `print()`.

Valgrind complains about the second example:

```
==82331== Invalid read of size 1
==82331==    at 0x400A8E: Printer::print()
==82331==    by 0x400967: main
==82331==  Address 0x5a1c040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==82331==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*)
==82331==    by 0x40095F: main
```

How can one detect errors of the first kind, perhaps using a tool like Valgrind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No static analysis tool is perfect. Static analysis tools like `valgrind` have a great track record of catching common programming bugs.

But they can't catch 100% of them.

My approach to try to avoid making these kinds of programming bugs, as much as possible, is defensive programming discipline that aims to prove, by contract, that these classes of programming bugs will be logically impossible. This includes things like:

1. Using smart pointers instead of references and pointers. You can prove, by contract, that using smart pointers results in references to objects that go out of scope becoming logically impossible.
2. Using iterators and standard library algorithms, instead of the classical `for (size_t i=0; i<container.size(); ++i)` approach. With clearly defined beginning and ending iterators running off the end of arrays becomes logically impossible. Plus, as an extra bonus, the code will require less changes if, for some reason, the choice of containers gets switched.

In your case, it's pretty much impossible for a runtime-only static analysis tool to detect this. The eventual compiled code contains absolutely nothing that, at runtime, officially marks the temporary as going out of scope. The generated code allocates a stack frame sufficient to accomodate both the automatic-scoped variable, and the temporary that gets passed as a parameter. After the constructor call completes, no explicit call gets generated to mark the temporary as being destroyed. I don't see how `valgrind`, or any other static analysis tool, could possibly know this.

Perhaps if the temporary's class has an explicit destructor, it would theoretically possible for a generic static analysis tool to know that the class instance is now destroyed, by the virtue of its destructor getting invoked.

But this goes to show you that there is no perfect answer. Even the programming practices I mentioned will also not prevent 100% of the problems; and they sometimes introduce their own complexity that must be taken into consideration (like circular references, when using smart pointers).

Comment: `valgrind` isn't a static analysis tool.

Comment: I think it's just an object lesson (pun intended) that it's a bad idea to store passed references in any way that persists longer than the function argument they're passed in. For any call the passed reference may refer to a temporary object, and upon return it will then refer to an invalid object, and the member will then be useless. Maybe compilers should be made to generate a warning for such a situation.

Comment: @BlairHoughton - How do you propose that the compiler, when compiling a function call that passes a reference to a temporary as a parameter, can figure out that the called function stores the passed reference somewhere, when the compiler may not have ever compiled the source code to the called function, at any point in known recorded history, since time began eons ago?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik well I mean, if we're talking about a compiler with an abstract syntax tree; `if( search_rvalue( current_scope.passed_references, current_rvalue ) != NULL )` add a deep copy of the current rvalue tree to a map keyed with a descriptor struct of the lvalue. if you really wanted to it's not totally impossible to let the parser watch for conditions of lvalue matching. then its just a matter of stack tracing to see if the rvalue should be re-evaluated